# android.net.sip send instant message?

Tags: java, android, sip

I am trying to make something similar to Skype for learning purposes. I was looking into `android.net.sip` package for the same and I noticed that it only supports VoIP out of the box. SIP, however, is capable of both video calls and instant messaging, as mentioned in the docs. There is no example of how to do that.

There is `JAIN-SIP` but that is very low-level. Others are C/C++ ports to Java using JNI.

So, how can one send instant message using Android's SIP package?

Answer (score 0):

Android's SIP stack will do the signaling for call setup ( and it is indeed built on top of JAIN-SIP). If you want to do something more than what it offers, you have to go "very low level".  So I think you have answered your own question.

To build something "like skype" is going to take a lot of work over and above the signaling. If you are looking for an open source project "like skype" check out jitsi (which also uses JAIN-SIP). Ask on the JITSI mailing list about ports to Android. You may get some useful information from there. Of course, that will take away from your "learning purpose" because there will be nothing left to do if it is already done. Sigh...

Anyway, if you want to use JAIN-SIP and insist on struggling, there's some recent activity on setting up the package names for JAIN-SIP on android so they will not collide with the native SIP stack.